# Have a URL generate TwiML response in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, twilio, twilio-twiml

We are using the 'twilio-ruby' library in our application. The Twilio service is working as expected, text messages are being sent and received to and from our clients as expected. However, when there is an incoming message, there is a 500 from the server (11200 HTTP retrieval failure). I believe we need to generate a TwiML response and that will stop the error. I am just uncertain as to how I would do that. I am working in a rails application, would I want to generate inside the controller? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Ricky from Twilio here. There's a blog postthat  walks through [setting up a Rails app to respond with TwiML in a bit more in depth](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html) but you are correct that would want to generate the TwiML from within the controller. A simple example using the Twilio ruby gem would look like this:

```
  def sms
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Message 'Hey there. Congrats on integrating Twilio into your Rails 4 app.'
    end

    render xml: response.to_xml
  end
```

This is outlined with more detail in the blog post but in order for Twilio to be able to POST to this endpoint you'll also want to make sure CSRF is disabled in your controller. You can do so by adding the following line:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks for the reply @rickyrobinett